# "submit and post to Facebook" button

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, express, facebook-graph-api

I feel very lost now because it looks like FB is taking a way the custom features in the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) method. In the past if I wanted to have a "submit and post to facebook" on my webapp. I would use features like "picture", "caption", and "dsecription". This was perfect because when users make a review they can click on the "submit and post to facebook" and they will share the review data that they entered and I would generate an image based off their review.(like show parts of the text of the review). It looks like Facebook is deprecating these very useful parameters. I don't know why. The users can agree to share the post(image that comes with it) or not.

And I was able to do a redirect that had a returned query string that told me if the user clicked cancel (If they clicked cancel then I could just not save the review in my DB). I think they already got rid of that. Another plus is that I didn't have to have the user signup with my site or ask them special permissions.

Can someone please tell me how to add this type of feature now. "submit and post to facebook" .

I need to make sure that they share to FB was successful. The query string that they deprecated helped me out before.

With open graph I'm not sure if it can help be with this dynamic review data.

Comment: Under which limited conditions you can get a return value from the Feed or Share dialog, is described in the documentation. And if you want to share your user reviews with the data the user has entered, then you need to create a unique URL for each review, that returns the relevant OG meta tags.

Comment: The unique URL is based off the review they are about to place. how could I supply the url ,the URL contains the ID of the review. so they need to submit the review then I create the review in DB then I will be able to have the id from the DB to represent the review. url looks like /review/1234hkj34f

Answer (score 3):

For the picture, you have to specify the `picture` parameter in your request (cf. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#params ).

In a more general way, in order to define a description, an image or any other details of a webpage shared on Facebook, you'll need to implement open graph tags in your head section, for instance:

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

I'd advice you to have a look at the Webmaster - Sharing help page of Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

Comment: lets say a user make a review for different companies and they click a share and post to facebook, I know now that I could share a url that contains template info like review info and the description and stuff. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to send the url to FB. I tried when user clicks the button do an AJAX request and return the review id. I do that because the page shared can only be shared if the review was successfully inserted to the DB. url would be something like /review/424123423. I know FB blocks the pop up. do you know of a workaround?